# Hide all the radio buttons of a group

Tags: c#, asp.net

I should disable all the radio buttons belonging to a group

I have an asp.net page containing several checks. I should make sure that depending on the option selected inside a listbox, a certain group of radio buttons will be hide or disabled.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="modelTypeSelectIN" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="modelTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> SELEZIONA IL TIPO DI FINITURA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="air_IN">AIR</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="wide_IN">WIDE</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="sound_IN">SOUND</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="wave_IN">WAVE</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="box_IN">BOX</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="plana_IN">PLANA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="planaFG_IN">PLANA FULL GLASS</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


<div class="box" runat="server" id="BoxProva"><asp:RadioButton ID="sup3" GroupName="Superfici" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" /><span><span class="img" runat="server"><img src="~/In/Superfici/AIR_SLIGHTGRAIN/AIR SLIGHTGRAIN_8016_IN LUCE.png" alt="" runat="server"></span>PROVA DI FILTRO</span><div class="image-box"><img src="~/In/Superfici/AIR_SLIGHTGRAIN/AIR SLIGHTGRAIN_8016_IN LUCE.png" alt="" runat="server"></div></div>

<div class="box" runat="server" id="BoxProva"><asp:RadioButton ID="sup4" GroupName="Superfici" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" /><span><span class="img" runat="server"><img src="~/In/Superfici/AIR_SLIGHTGRAIN/AIR SLIGHTGRAIN_8017_IN LUCE.png" alt="" runat="server"></span>PROVA DI FILTRO</span><div class="image-box"><img src="~/In/Superfici/AIR_SLIGHTGRAIN/AIR SLIGHTGRAIN_8017_IN LUCE.png" alt="" runat="server"></div></div>
```

This is a event handler:

```
protected void SlightGrain7016InLuce_CheckedChanged(object sender, 
 EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SlightGrain7016InLuce.Checked)
        {
            BoxProva.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have? The things you've tried?

Comment: Code added, sorry.

Comment: Did you try disabling the group box itself.

Comment: Yes, but this is an example! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this will work , use function to managed your radio button group ...

```
        // Thsi will trigger When Dropdownlist selected option changed
    protected void modelTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (modelTypeSelectIN.SelectedItem.Text == "WIDE")
        {
            Disable_GroupSuperfici_RaddioButton();
        }
        else
        {
            Enable_GroupSuperfici_RaddioButton();
        }
    }

    // This function Enable particular group of button
    private void Disable_GroupSuperfici_RaddioButton()
    {
        sup3.Enabled = false;
        sup4.Enabled = false;
        //RadioButton1.Enabled = false;
        //RadioButton2.Enabled = false;
    }

    // This function disable particular group of button
    private void Enable_GroupSuperfici_RaddioButton()
    {
        sup3.Enabled = true;
        sup4.Enabled = true;
        //RadioButton1.Enabled = true;
        //RadioButton2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: But in this way I would have to individually indicate all the radio buttons to be disabled or hidden. I would like to ensure that ALL the radiobuttons belonging to the group "GroupName =" Surfaces "" are disabled or hidden.

Comment: exclude whatever RadioButton that you dont need in the function...let say you have 3 RadioButton  , 
 [ group1 = RadioButton1 , RadioButton2]
 [group2 = RadioButton3 ] .
Let say if you want to disable group 1 only , then your function shall only include RadioButton1 , RadioButton2 and not RadioButton3

Comment: By writing sup3.Disable, for example, I only disable the radio button with ID sup3, while I would like to disable all the radios belonging to a group.

Comment: when you call out the function , it already call out "group" of  radio button and disable all of them depend on your need  . i understand you use group properties in raion button object but think out of the box , this is not the only way you managed object , you can managed them in above propse way and still get the effert you want , which is disable multipel object . Function allow you to reuse it later time , i believe you do aware , right?